# Need MS R Server API to return a dataframe in JSON row-by-row format, not column-by-column

Tags: r, sql-server

My web developers cannot work with the JSON format generated by the MRSDeploy found in Microsoft ML Service Server.

Example:

The Data frame to be returned:

```
foo bar prediction
  1   a .98
  2   b .75
  3   c .55
```

The PublishService code:

```
# Publish as service using publishService() function from 
api <- publishService(
"MyPrediction_v1",
code = function_InOut,
inputs = list(foo = "numeric", bar = "character"),
outputs = list(OutputDataSet = "data.frame"),
v = version
)
```

The Current Return

```
{
  "foo": [1, 2, 3],
  "bar": ["a", "b", "c"]
  "prediction" [.98,.75,.55]
}
```

The Preferred Return

```
{"Results": [
    {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar":"a",
    "prediction":.98
    },
    {
    "foo": 2,
   "bar":"b",
   "prediction":.75
    },
    {
   "foo": 2,
   "bar":"c",
   "prediction":.55
}
]
}
```

How do I get a row-by-row return?   column-by-column is not desired?